# Do Pokemon have specific spawning areas and times?

Tags: pokemon-go

So after a few weeks, I've noticed that Growlithes have started spawning somewhat regularly, which is great!

But over the past few weeks, I've noticed that they only spawn in a specific place (a park), and only after dark. It makes sense, being a "dog" Pokemon, and being a dark type.

Additionally, other evidence of this is water type Pokemon - Krabby, Squirtle, Horsea, Magikarp - all have been spawning more regularly near water.

Is there anything about times and locations to do with Pokemon spawning? Is there any kinds of lists to show what Pokemon spawn where, and when?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you found are called Nest (https://pokemongohub.net/post/wiki/nests/) They are a specific places on the map where certain pokemon will spawn more frequently. The pokemon change every 2 weeks.

As for the night part, Growlithe is only a fire pokemon so it is not affected by the greater spawn rate of ghost/dark pokemon at night. (https://pokemongohub.net/generation-2/researching-nocturnal-specie-pokemon-go-generation-1-2/)

Water pokemon are known to spawn more next to water. (https://rankedboost.com/pokemon-go/catching-locations/#water)

To know which pokemon are in which next you can go here : https://thesilphroad.com/atlas

Comment: Well, I can understand the "nest" part, except for the fact that only a couple will spawn at a time, and they been spawning there between 5-8pm, for the past 2 months.

Answer (score 1):

Growlithe may also spawn more often in areas where they would usually be a rare spawn (such as certain parks), during Sunny/Clear weather.

It doesn't necessarily mean it is a nest; nests you should see frequent spawns of a specific pokemon that may not normally appear at that location, and regardless of weather (though even more frequent if weather boosted).